# Excel does not accept custom cell format for cents

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

I have a spreadsheet containing cent amounts, and I am trying to format the amounts such that the last two zeroes are separated from the rest of the figure by a space, and from then on thousands are separated by spaces again.

The format that I have tried is:

```
_ * # ### 00_ ;_ * -# ### 00_ ;_ * "-"??_ ;_ @_
```

(there are no decimals in the data because everything is rounded to the nearest cent).

The problem is, Excel automatically converts this format back to

```
_ * ### #00_ ;_ * -### #00_ ;_ * "-"??_ ;_ @_
```

the moment I press OK.

Is there away to achieve the format I am describing?

Comment: How about `### ### ### 00` ?

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work.

Comment: Can you give some example unformatted numbers and the way you want them to appear?

Comment: The data come in this form: 1000000, 2000000, 2000000 etc.

Comment: And you want them to appear like this? 10 000 00, 20 000 00, 20 000 00

Comment: I'm not an expert but i think your problem is in the last bit. Here `_ * # ### 00_ ;_ * -# ### 00_ ;_ * "-"??_ ;_-@_- ` works for me. (only last set is changed)

Comment: @Andi yes exactly, do you think that's possible?

Comment: And wouldn't `# ### 00` be enough here?

Comment: @Rik When I enter `_ * # ### 00_ ;_ * -# ### 00_ ;_ * "-"??_ ;_ @_ ` Excel reverts it back to `_ * ### #00_ ;_ * -### #00_ ;_ * "-"??_ ;_ @_ `

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my Excel?

Comment: It's exactly as i typed it. But perhaps its a localization issue. (Have a dutch version here) Does the `# ### 00` also not work? (no `;` etc to confuse Excel)

Comment: try this instead, perhaps it doesn't like unqualified spaces: `###" "###" "###" "00;-###" "###" "###" "00;"-"`

Comment: @Rik the code I pasted from your comment provided an error but see I updated my comment - I only used the last bit and Excel converted that back to its own format. When I just use `# ### 00` it gets reverted back to `### #00` once I press OK. Perhaps a setting I need to change somewhere?

Comment: @Andi, thanks, that does it! I wonder why that would be!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per discussion in the comments, it appears Adriaan's version of Excel (or possibly Windows settings) doesn't like spaces not contained in quotes. This custom format solves the problem:

```
###" "###" "###" "00;-###" "###" "###" "00;"-"
```